# Android JSoup make the app crash

Tags: java, android, jsoup

When I open the app I get the message "the application stop". What could be the reason?

The main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call super.onCreate() first.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Then load the layout.

        // Find textView3 in layout and set it's text to HTML code.
        // There's no need to create a new TextView() here.
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(getHtmlCode());
      }

      // Structure your code. If it's a larger block that does one thing,
      // extract it into a method.
      private String getHtmlCode() {
        try {
          Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/").get();
          Element content = doc.select("a").first();
         // return content.text();
          return "kktt";
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load HTML code",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return "kk";
        }
      }
    }

////Elements divs = doc.select("div#test");   //select all the content of the div tags with the id attribute set to test
```

*I add the jar to libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move getHtmlCode() in to AsyncTask. You should not do network operations on onCreate() method or the Main thread. So Move your code to AsyncTask. and can update the UI in AsyncTask itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to the following permission to the Android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After adding the above permission, you need to move the code inside the method getHtmlCode() to an async task or thread. After that you are good to go.